# How to update parameter of all objects in a model - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to update a parameter in a Django model for all objects in the DB. The values will be different for each object, and I'm trying to work out whether I can do this as a batch update, or whether I have to iterate through each item and save each one separately.

The model I'm using is an extension of the Django auth user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=0)
```

If I get all objects as follows:

```
queryset = User.objects.all()
```

then loop through these and update `position`:

```
for user in queryset:
    user.position = #SOME FUNCTION
```

do I have to do `user.save()` within the `for` loop? Or can I update each item and then save all at once to the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't have a bulk update but what you can do is use an atomic transaction to improve performance by committing all update statements once.

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    for user in queryset:
        user.position = #SOME FUNCTION
        user.save()
```

There will still be `len(queryset)` inserts but they will be grouped into a single transaction.

Comment: Just noticed the user.position and user.save() statements should be indented on this... I can't edit for some reason